# How to store different values with same key in memcache?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

My application runs on App Engine and different parts of my application needs to store different type of values to memcache with the same key. In the application there are two classes that is caching values with `Link` as keys. One class is storing `Boolean` and the other `ArrayList` as value. However when they need to work with the same `Link` now there is a conflict. So to avoid this I came up with 3 options:

1. Use `String`s as keys. Convert `Link` objects to string and prefix them with the class names that is using it when putting and getting values to memcache.
2. Use *namespace* feature of memcache to distinguish keys. However, namespaces are typically used for multitenancy purposes, so it doesn't seem right.
3. Create wrapper classes for the key in different parts of application. But this adds complexity.

I am planning to use the first option since it is the simplest one. What are my other options? Are there any best practices out there? This is the first time I am using memcache, I am not sure which path to take.

Comment: Why don't you store the whole object or a dictionary representing the object in memcache, with all the values you require in a single key ?

Comment: @TimHoffman: A colleague suggested that too. But, those two classes are totally unrelated and unnecessary information will be exposed to both in that case. If `Link` object was not easily converted to String (vice versa) I would do that instead of option #1.